# How to know what installed modules are contrib modules from the GUI?

Tags: installation

I wish to remove all contrib modules so I could upgrade my core from version 9 to version 10.

I have installed several contrib modules, some time has passed and my problem is that for some modules, I may not recall if they are contrib or core, when looking at `example.com/admin/modules/uninstall`.

How to know what installed modules are contrib modules from the GUI?
If this can't be done from GUI so I guess I have to navigate to `WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT/modules`.

Comment: Any module not listed as "Core".

Comment: @Kevin in `/admin/modules` there are some core modules such as those under "Web services" not under "Core" which are indeed core. That said, in `/admin/modules/uninstall` there is no categorization at all, at least not in Drupal 9.5.8

Comment: Just be aware that uninstalling modules will also delete configuration that depends on the module, and by extension, content tied to those configurations. You might want to think twice before uninstalling modules.

Comment: @Joseph thanks, the actual case in hand here is about 2-3 modules which besides one (Asset Injector) don't have any data or at least I don't recall ever adding data to them and I have asked the question to get a principle answer. Other than that I fully agree with you. Before uninstalling a module one should probably backup its data and then delete this data. I have full backups of Asset Injector's resources and should re-backup just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to remove contrib modules to upgrade core.  Instead, you should upgrade the contrib modules to Drupal 10-compatible versions and then upgrade core from 9 to 10.

To check if all of your contrib modules are ready for Drupal 10, you can use the [Upgrade Status module](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status).  Install the module and go to Reports as an administrator, and then choose Upgrade Status.  You can then check which contrib modules are ready for D10.

You only need to uninstall a module to upgrade if it is not D10-compatible.

Comment: This answers to *I wish to remove all contrib modules so I could upgrade my core from version 9 to version 10.* I agree: Removing all the contributed modules to upgrade Drupal core is probably not necessary. The question does not say which contributed modules have been installed, nor if any of those modules do not have a Drupal 10 version. I understand that the explicit question is how to understand from the user interface which modules are part of Drupal core, but what reported in this answer should be taken in consideration from the OP.

Comment: The Upgrade Status module is also probably the closest thing to the UI the OP is looking for